# Eigenvalues of symmetric band matrix using Accelerate framework

Tags: ios, macos, linear-algebra, accelerate-framework

In a macOS/iOS code base, I've got a real symmetric band matrix that can be anywhere from 10 × 10 to about 500 × 500, and I need to compute whether all its eigenvalues are greater than (or equal to) a certain threshold. So I only strictly need to know the lowest eigenvalue, in case that helps.

Is there any function or set of functions in [Apple's Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate) that can provide a full or partial solution to this? Ideally with a cost proportional to the number of non-zero entries.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node48.html), it appears there's a set of LAPACK functions that compute eigenvalues efficiently for banded symmetric matrices. (LAPACK is implemented a part of the Accelerate framework.)

As I understand it, [`ssbtrd`](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/df5/group__real_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_ga5f8af8f03cb65598c00693417300b652.html) followed by [`ssterf`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d24/group__aux_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_ga6f005e62dd179b39d847eadbb62dbead.html) should do the trick.

> SSBTRD reduces a real symmetric band matrix A to symmetric
> tridiagonal form T by an orthogonal similarity transformation:
> Q**T * A * Q = T.

> SSTERF computes all eigenvalues of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix
> using the Pal-Walker-Kahan variant of the QL or QR algorithm.